# Deploy a net6 mvc web app on iis using webdeploy package

Tags: c#, iis, .net-6.0, webdeploy

I created a web delpoyment package using the "Web Deploy Package" wizard from Visual Studio 2022.

The output is a web package and a cmd file to configure.

My goal is to install the package on a remote server as **new** application with a custom **new** application pool. A default web site already exists.

I got this working using parameterization

```
webpackage-deploy.cmd /Y /M:iis-machinename /U:user_name /P:user_password
```

The issue is i always get the default application pool.

What i have already tried was to add

```
<IncludeAppPool>true</IncludeAppPool>
<IncludeIisSettings>true</IncludeIisSettings>
```

to the pubxml publish file. This lead to a custom parameter, which gets ignored when i install.

```
-enableLink:AppPoolExtension
```

which also made no difference.

Looking inside the webpackage in **archive.xml** the deployment is alsways a IISAPP. As much as my resarch went the IISAPP can not assign a application pool.

I also found the apphostconfig provider, which in my case didn't work because i have to specify more parameter, e.g. the physical path which i do not want to configure while installing (the IISAPP uses the inetpub/wwwroot folder which is what i want to achieve )

Comment: This link may help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961535/application-pool-not-set-when-deploying-msdeploy-iisapp-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961535/application-pool-not-set-when-deploying-msdeploy-iisapp-package).